# Skip attribute if filled in Magmi

Tags: magento, magmi

I'm working on a client site where the description is only sometimes provided in the data feed, other times the data feed has an empty value for the description and it's entered manually. Currently the issue I'm seeing is that, when importing, Magmi will replace any manually entered descriptions with the blank field provided with the data field

Is there a way to tell Magmi not to overwrite an attribute if the value in the CSV is blank so that it doesn't delete manually entered data?

Comment: is the description COMPLETELY blank? no null or space or anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a lot of field types, Magmi will treat a blank value as a 'do not update'.

Text fields will update verbatum though, so Magmi has an answer for this - replace your blank description fields with;

```
__MAGMI_IGNORE__
```

And Magmi will treat that field as though it werent in the data for that particular line item.

Example here on the Magmi Wiki http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=MAGMI_IGNORE